# Re-arrange data with multiple keyword in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have data like this in excel appearing two rows:

```
Row1            Row2 
VIN             ******
NAME            JOHN, DOE
OCCUPATION      BUSINESS
GENDER          MALE
VIN             *****
NAME            JANE DOE
OCCUPATION      OTHER
GENDER          FEMALE
```

How can I get data like this in excel:

```
VIN           NAME                          OCCUPATION          GENDER
****       JOHN DOE ONE                      BUSINESS           MALE
****       JANE DOE                           OTHER           FEMALE
```

Comment: With a formula ? with VB.NET ? or with VBA ? the tags are important, the explanation is important too, and most important is to show to us what you are tried to do.

Comment: If it is excel-vba it cannot be VB.NET - the words associated with the tags say so

Comment: An `Index/Match` could work, what have you tried?  Do you need a macro or would formulas work?

Comment: Hi Bruce, any one that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your data starts in A2:

[image]

You can use `Index/Match` with `SMALL()` to get the data. This assumes your data repeats, as in the image and your original table.

`=INDEX($B$1:$B$9,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$9=E$2,ROW($B$1:$B$9)),ROWS(($A$1:A1))))`

(Note: Enter as an array formula, with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

Where `E$2` is the title of the category, i.e. `VIN`/`Name`/`Occupation`,etc.

If you set up the categories in a row, you can use the formula and drag over/down to fill it out:

[image]

And finally, to hide the errors, just wrap `IFERROR()` around it, i.e. `=IFERROR([formula],"")`.